# print window is not showing

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

My below asp.net server code is redirecting page without showing print window:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), "printGrid", "javascript:window.print();", true);
Page.Response.Redirect(Page.Request.Url.ToString(), true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add some JavaScript to the page and also redirect to another page, the JavaScript isn't going to execute.

Remove the redirect to allow the print dialog to open.

Comment: after the print i want to redirect the page, how to do that ?

Comment: @hashimfajar - use the `window.onafterprint` event handler to set the new document location. You don't want to redirect until the print dialog is all done with.

Comment: -for  below crieteria --                                  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), "printGrid", "javascript:window.print();", true);

        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "ShowPopup();", true);